# CAN WE PLEASE BLOCK TITLES WRITTEN IN ALL CAPS?

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

Ironically, I think it would be a good idea to auto-block titles that contain all (or most) capital letters.  The obvious idea of doing this is a cheap way to attract more attention to the one's question. This is wrong and shouldn't be allowed.  Most of these question will be quickly edited, wasting peoples time.

I have two possible ways we could implement this but I encourage anyone with any other ideas to edit in or answer a proposal

- **Auto Capitalize**: If a question is submitted with an all capital title the question title should automatically switch to Capitalize formatting (every word's first letter is capitalized while the others remain lowercase, like the Right Click > Transformations > Capitalize on Macs.)
- **Warn OP**: When submitting a question that contains an all capital title, the OP is blocked from submitting the question and a warning indicating that "The title cannot contain all capital letters.". They are not able to submit the question until it has been fixed.

This should also be added to the help center.

Comment: RELATED: [BLOCK QUESTIONS IN ALL CAPS](https://META.STACKEXCHANGE.COM/Q/121301)... and [Adding “all capitals in the question title” to the quality filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219827)

Comment: Note that "Capitalize on Macs" is *not* a good solution to this anyway. A good one would be ["Implementing Proper English Title Capitalization"](https://karl-voit.at/2015/05/25/elisp-title-capitalization/).

Comment: @LangLangC Same idea but yeah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES WE COULD. I’d say we don’t need the hard block and  I enthusiastically agree with everything else you propose.

Most of this is covered in a post on the main site about quality filters on questions:

- [BLOCK QUESTIONS IN ALL CAPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps)

All caps is a valuable signal as is poor writing as are overly long and overly short posts. It lets us know the frame of mind and thought process of the person posting at the moment they entered the text.

Also, I dislike technical solutions to people problems in general and in specific here.

One thing I would support is a style guide extension to be written in [help] and perhaps summoning that and asking if the person realizes they are violating the style guide.

I would add the style guide to the bottom of this article or link to it from there.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior

Comment: What about the `Warn OP` method described in the question. We could warn them and provide that link. Even if it the OP can hit a `submit anyway` button.

Comment: I hear you @JBis -  I suggested a feature like that for insults and it wasn’t received well. We could try for something far less harmful like ALL CAPS and maybe it would get implemented since the detection is easier??? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313804/165931

Comment: I see what they're getting at but with the tech we have today with NLP it shouldn't be too difficult to detect things.  And I am sure one of the big names like Microsoft or **Google** would be happy to support SE and would want to flaunt the fact that **they** power tools on SE and SO that can detect these types of thinks.